# Automator or Applescript for custom script to download bank statements?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automator

What's the best tool to script to automate downloading statements from my bank and credit card companies' website in each of their statement download area?

All banks, credit card companies, and financial investment companies have an option to download monthly or quarterly statements as a PDF. Also known as paperless statements.

I want to write a script using perl, AppleScript, or Automator, or ?? that will auto fetch a monthly statement PDF from each site. (I am aware it will require editing for each site. e.g. editing URLs and possibly logins, as well as the URLs pointing to the page where the PDF statement is located once in the Downloads area.

This is similar to what Mint.com does where they fetch all your financial data. The difference between that and what I am asking for is that I just want the monthly statement that would normally be mailed to me. In some cases I have already signed up for paperless billing so they are putting the statements in the statement billing area. With some other accounts I have not yet signed up for paperless billing but the statements are already there.

No more than ten accounts. The URLs will be different and the ID and password will be different for each site. What I would like to do is write a script that will login to the site, traverse to the "Downloads" or "Statements" page (or what ever it is called on each respective site), and download the item which will have a link on that page.

Which tool is best to do this? Basically it's got to:
 1. Send the login credentials
 2. once logged in get the URL for the downloads page then,
 3. get the URL for the most recent statement.
 4. after a period of time or on completetion of the download it will log out the user.
 5. It will run the next script for the next site or loop back through the code inserting new variables for uid, password, NextSiteURL, NextSiteSteps/actions.

I want recommendations on which would be best perl, AppleScript, Automator. I would like to know which tool is best suited to this task or be directed to come code online that could be modified to do what I am asking.

If you are not clear on what I am asking for feel free to ask questions. I think this is pretty clear though.

Comment: Could you add which companies you would like to obtain data from?

Comment: in order to define the variables, how many banks are we talking about?

Comment: no more than ten banks/credit card companies

Comment: I recommend AppleScript for that. Tunes, you need to refine your question. In order to build your grand solution, you will have to ask specific questions for small bricks. Then I can advise you with AppleScript.

Comment: Here is an example. I got to a credit card site and there are links for each month. I am able to get Automator to get to the page but snagging the Monthly PDF statements is not working. The links go down the page and I would assume the are likely randomly generated. So URL Automator to snag the URL would not work because the following month the URL would change. So I need to find a way to get some script to find the text then snag the link.

Comment: Here is the text on the page:
Monthly Statement
View/Print | Save to PDF | View PDF with screen reader  05/17/2014

The link I want is "Save to PDF" which is linked to:
javascript:SetRedirectURL('StatementsPdfHandler.ashx?index=1&StmtIdx=12014&PDFType=PDF&StmtDate=05/17/2014%2012:00:00%20AM&OpenType=download&IsVersion1Call=False&FreqType=Monthly&Part=')

So how do I get it to traverse the text and find the first occurrence then run the script to download the current months statement? (Assuming I always want the first occurrence).